# How can I use invoke for fixing exception error?

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to write a code for taking fps at label while taking view from the camera.
So, I used task for that and I used timer but I got an error. I fixed the problem with using `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` but as far as I know it is not an effective way.
I want to fix this with using invoke. How should I write the code properly?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace projectimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        System.Timers.Timer timerFPS;
        


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        CameraConnection connnection;
        private bool btn_GetviewWasClicked = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            btn_Getview.Click += Btn_Getview_Click;

            timerFPS = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            timerFPS.Elapsed += TimerFPS_Elapsed;
            timerFPS.Start();

        }

        private void Btn_Getview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_GetviewWasClicked = true;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                connnection = new CameraConnection();
                connnection.Connect();
            });
            CameraConnection.DataReceived += CameraConnection_DataReceived;
        }


        private void TimerFPS_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            txt_fps.Text = Convert.ToString(CameraConnection.count);
            CameraConnection.count = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please provide only the **relevant** parts of your code. In particular the entire calculation seems pretty irrelevant to your problem. Where specifically do you get the error?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I will fix the code.I am getting the error at this part when I delete this code : CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; ////this is the part that I am getting error: txt_fps.Text = Convert.ToString(CameraConnection.count); @MakePeaceGreatAgain

Comment: You can use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`. In the winforms timer the `Tick` event (similar to `Elapsed` in your code) will be on the UI thread, so you don't need to use `Invoke` at all. See example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer.I will try this method but I am trying to learn invoke method but I could not understand.although I researched that.If you know about invoke method could you explain it to me in this code.I am little confused.@ wohlstad

Comment: Invoke posts a message to the UI thread's message queue.  the UI thread's message pump will call the passed delegate when the message is picked out of the queue and processed.  The processing context is the UI thread, not the thread of the Invoke caller . WinForms is not thread safe, changing CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is like disconnecting the check engine light.